# Akka Streams handling an Exception from a third party GraphStage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Hi I'm wondering if anyone can help my understanding with Exception handling from GraphStage's created by third parties.

I am using a GraphStage that throws an Exception and stops the stream. What I would like to do is to log all information about the error (everything that was passed into the GraphStage before failure) and continue processing. 
I've tried *recover* and *supervision strategy* but they don't allow the stream to continue.

Here's an example GraphStage that demonstrates my issue. I'm throwing an Exception explicitly this may not be best practice.

```
import akka.stream.{Attributes, FlowShape, Inlet, Outlet}
import akka.stream.stage.{GraphStage, GraphStageLogic, InHandler, OutHandler}

class TestStage extends GraphStage[FlowShape[Int, Int]] {

  private val in = Inlet[Int]("Test.in")
  private val out = Outlet[Int]("Test.out")
  override val shape = FlowShape.of(in, out)

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) with InHandler with OutHandler {

      setHandlers(in, out, this)

      override def onPush(): Unit = {
        val num = grab(in)
        if (num == 5) {
          throw new Exception(s"Number is 5")
        }
        push(out, num)
      }

      override def onPull(): Unit = pull(in)
    }
}

Source(1 to 10)
.via(Flow.fromGraph(new TestStage))
.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
.recover {
case e: Exception => e.getMessage
}
.runForeach(println)
```

This example that doesn't use a GraphStage does continue processing. So it seems an
Exception thrown from a GraphStage needs to be treated differently?

```
  Source(1 to 10)
  .map {
    case 5 => throw new Exception("5 is bad")
    case n => n
  }
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.resumingDecider))
  .runForeach(println)
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is documented behaviour of some of akka stream stages

[Error Handling in Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html?language=scala#supervision-strategies):

> The operators that support supervision strategies are explicitly documented to do so, if there is nothing in the documentation of an operator saying that it adheres to the supervision strategy it means it fails rather than applies supervision.

Or this [issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23376).

Comment: thanks it's good to know there is some information relating to this.  It seems to indicate Operators and Stages both need to be designed to handle supervision strategies if not there is nothing that can be done to keep the stream up and running on failure. Something to look out for when using a third party stage!